# Render refactoring leads to undefined function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React class that functions correctly when written as such:

```
const LoginContainer = React.createClass({
  authenticate: () => {
      console.log('TODO: Finish authenticating');
  },

  render: function() {
      return (
        <Login authenticate={this.authenticate} />
      );
    }
});
```

To conform to the style guide we are using, I should use the arrow shorthand for `render`:

```
render: () =>
  (
    <Login authenticate={ this.authenticate } />
  ),
```

However, as soon as I rewrite this, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined

How can I get a reference to `authenticate` within my arrow function?

Please note that I understand the value of `this` is scoped differently in an arrow function, but what I'm trying to figure out is how to get the binding correct *within a React class*. This may be more of a `React` question than vanilla JS.

Comment: Give this a shot: `<Login authenticate={() => this.authenticate() } />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: @MikeC Added clarification.

Comment: @MisterEpic The problem is still the same. Arrow functions explicitly set `this` but you need `this` to be correctly set. Why not just use standard method syntax? `render() { return (<Login authenticate={this.authenticate} />); }`

Comment: @MikeC Style conformance for an existing codebase where linting indicates a preference for the shorthand arrow.

Comment: @lux Your syntax does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions lexically binds context so that `this` refers to the context of the outer scope.

Comment: Correct. So in your constructor you can do something like : `this. authenticate = this. authenticate.bind(this);` and then it should work

Comment: @erichardson30 No constructor when creating a `React` class like I am doing.